# turning points everywhere continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

Does a REAL, everywhere continuous function exist which has an infinite number of turning points but does NOT use trig functions ? I think not but having trouble formalising my reasons. (The function need not be periodic but its domain and range must be all REAL x)

Comment: Maybe the Gamma Function: $\Gamma(x) = \int^\infty_0 t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$ for $x<0$?

Comment: Not continuous for all x, the graph shows discontinuities.

Answer (score 2):

How about the piecewise linear function whose graph goes through $$\dots,(-4,0),(-3,1),(-2,0),(-1,1),(0,0),(1,1),(2,0),(3,1),(4,0),\dots$$

You could smooth it out by making it piecewise quadratic instead.

(EDIT:) Explicitly: write $\overline x$ for the remainder when you divide $x$ by $2$ (with integer quotient) so, e.g., $\overline{7.3}=1.3$ because $7.3=2\times3+1.3$. Then the function $f(x)=\overline x^2(\overline x-2)^2$ is continuous (indeed, continuously differentiable) and has a turning point at each integer.

MORE EDIT: The Riemann zeta function is known to have infinitely many zeros on the line, real past of $s$ equals one-half. So the function $f(t)={\rm Re\ }\zeta(.5+it)$ fills the bill.

Comment: No, that won't do. what is that PW function and where are its turning points...it cannot be smoothed out to give endless turning points.

Comment: Sure it can. Just done.

Comment: That's just smoke and mirrors. Trig formulas exist for functions expressing the remainder, quotient, floor, ceiling, int part etc etc...one of which can be found here (http://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/Quotient/27/02/) So your formula is in fact a trig function and as such does not meet the condtions I set out.

Comment: Trig formulas exist for every function. Look, take any doubly-infinite sequence of real numbers, $\cdots <a_{-3}<a_{-2}<a_{-1}<a_0<a_1<a_2<a_3<\cdots$, let $f(a_i)$ be zero if $i$ is even, one if $i$ is odd, and draw a curve connecting them smoothly, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: In that case please provide the (real) trig formula for exp(x). I don't include inf Fourier series.

Comment: You're making up more and more conditions as you go along. It would have been much better, had you thought out exactly what you did and did not want before posting the question, and then included everything in your original post. As it is, I'm tired of playing a game where you keep on changing the rules.

Comment: What the heck – here's another family of examples. Let $S$ be any infinite, discrete set of reals, let $f(x)$ be the square of the distance from $x$ to $S$.

Comment: I am not making up more conditions, merely pointing out that Fourier series are impermissible as they using trigs. My original questions stands as stated with no amendments. Your last example does not work either, what is the square of the distance of a number (x) to a set (S)...how is that defined ?

Comment: You are constantly making up more conditions. Every time someone gives you a perfectly good answer, "oh, no, that's not what I meant, I meant to exclude that kind of answer". Anyway, distance from a real number to an infinite discrete set of real numbers is defined in the most obvious way possible; the set partitions the real line into a set of disjoint intervals, the number is in exactly one of those intervals, you see how far it is from the two set points delimiting that interval, you choose the smaller of the two numbers.

Comment: But what's wrong with $f(x)=\overline x^2(\overline x-2)^2$ example? What's wrong with the one using the zeta-function?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Yes, still here. The problem with the f(x) you suggested is that it is a trig function in disguise, it can be re-written using trigs and as such is inadmissible. It's a straightforward question and no one has yet given a satisfactory answer.  To reiterate; can a function be continuous for all real x and have an inf number of turning points but NOT use trigs (or obviously anything reducible to trigs). The answers thus far provided have failed.

Comment: The (Riemann) Zeta function is a function of a complex variable. My question specifically said a function whose domain and range are REAL

Comment: $f(t)={\rm Re\ }\zeta(.5+it)$ is a real-valued function of the real variable $t$. And as I have already remarked, every function can be rewritten using trig functions, so it looks like you're ruling out all possible answers before we even begin.

Comment: Yes, using trigs AND complex numbers. But can you do it using trigs alone ? My original question makes it clear that complex numbers are not to be used.

Comment: "Using trigs alone"? Now you want it done, using trigs? Now I really don't know what you want.

Comment: YOu said that every fn can be expressed using trigs ( I assume you mean an inf trig series?). Can you express exp(x) using a finite number of trigs (no complex numbers) ?

Comment: Any finite number of real trig functions will yield a periodic function, which $e^x$ is not, so of course it's impossible to express $e^x$ using a finite number of trig functions. The fact remains that the real part of $\zeta(.5+it)$ is a real-valued function of a real variable, with no trig functions in sight. Likewise, the square of the distance from $x$ to the nearest prime number.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Of course such functions exist. The [Airy functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) come to mind.

Comment: Airy functions are defined in terms of trigs.

Comment: There are many ways to define them and not all of them include trig functions. For example, you can define them as the solutions to the differential equation $$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-xy=0.$$ At this point, you realize that your requirement "does NOT use trig functions" is not very well defined. Does the function $f(x) = x+sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)$ use trig functions?

Comment: The DE is not a function and f(x) contains trigs because I can see them (regardless that the function is equal to 1+x) besides it has no turning points.